# awk to add missing to sequential order if id not found in file

Tags: awk

The `awk` below will look for the ids in `file1` in `$2` of `file2` and if they match print the `$2`. If an id is missing or not found in `file2` (like ARRR and AAAA), I can not figure out how to add it to them to the lines in the output as missing in `$3` following the same format. That is with the next sequential number in `$1`, the id from `file1` in `$2`, and the word missing in `$3`.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$2 in A' file1 file2
```

**file1** `space delimited`

```
AARS
AARS2
AARS2;TMEM151B
ARRR
AAAS
AAAA
AADAC
```

**file2** `tab-delimited`

```
1   AARS     100.00
2   AARS2    100.00
3   AARS2;TMEM151B   100.00
4   AAAS     100.00
5   AADAC    100.00
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
1   AARS     100.00
2   AARS2    100.00
3   AARS2;TMEM151B   100.00
4   AAAS     100.00
5   AADAC    100.00
6   ARRR    missing
7   AAAA    missing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }$2 in a{ delete a[$2] }
     END{ for(i in a) print ++FNR,i,"missing" }1' file1 OFS='\t' file2
```

The output:

```
1   AARS     100.00
2   AARS2    100.00
3   AARS2;TMEM151B   100.00
4   AAAS     100.00
5   AADAC    100.00
6   AAAA    missing
7   ARRR    missing
```